# Why doesn't gradle return dependencies for another projects?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have the following build script (webapp:build.gradle):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    project(':api')
}
```

When I run `gradle dependencies webapp:dependencies` in command line I get:

```
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

No configurations
:webapp:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :webapp
------------------------------------------------------------

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
No dependencies

runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

testCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
No dependencies

testRuntime - Runtime classpath for source set 'test'.
No dependencies
```

There was nothing to be said about dependency from `api` project. Why? What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because You haven't specified configuration name for this dependency. It should be e.g.:

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':api')
}
```

**webapp/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':api')
}
```

**webapp/settings.gradle**

```
include 'api'
```

**webapp/api/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```